# lazy loading - when does it download chunk files?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, lazy-loading

I am using vue.js . I want to use lazy loading for routes for example.

Let's say I built the project with webpack by firing (`npm run build`).

Then, as `webpack` started building, it would generate all the `chunks` separately.

**Question**: It's said that when using lazy routing, only that js file gets loaded on which route we will be on. Right? If that's so, when moving to another route, another chunk js file should get loaded. Where will this chunk come from?

1. from the server? if so, we completely lose the point of SPA, because
   for each route change, we go to server and ask the necessary js
   file.
2. If not from the server, then it's already downloaded when we first
   loaded the page. If that's so, why was it a good idea to split it
   into chunks if first page load would still need to download all the
   chunks?

Comment: It is loaded from the server. But why do you think you lose the point of an SPA?

Comment: SPA has one of the great features. Your first load time is slow, but then when moving to routes, it's super fast because you don't make requests to server. That's why.

Comment: I see. Chunks are initially loaded from the server but they can then be cached. And to alleviate the slow initial load some techniques can be used such as using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to detect when a link comes into view for example and start loading the chunk in the background so that when you actually click a link the chunk is already available.

Comment: Thanks @HusamIbrahim for your answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be downloaded from the server, however you don't loose all the SPA advantages as the other chunks could be preloaded while staying on the initial page. That is rendered from the initial chunk.
If you want to be fast, you can't load everything from the server in one go. You will still have to communicate to the server. Point of SPA is more to get rid of redownloading html/css/js boilerplate and focus on feeding app with new data (and view, logic in your case).